# Configuring tomcat server dynamically?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, server.xml

I need to configure my tomcat server dynamically. In fact, when the Host machine got  an Ip adress  from the router dhcp, the tomcat changes dynamically to listen  on the new IP address.

Thank you for your help and sorry  for  the  bad formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding on `0.0.0.0` and see if this helps. Technically, [`0.0.0.0` means 'listening on all the configured network interfaces'](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1).